# qt cross compiling

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile QT for ARM. 
But the linker requires "--sysroot" option to be added for linking files. 
So in qmake.conf file, we added under QMAKE_LFLAGS.

But when we compile, its adding this even for initial tools build on the x86 PC. So gcc complains and gives error.

The cross compiler tool chain which doesnt have a .pc file.

Please let me know where to add the "--sysroot" so that this is added only when it tries to cross compile.

Thanks.
Hari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using qmake [scopes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-advanced-usage.html#scopes-and-conditions) - specifically [platform scope variables](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-advanced-usage.html#platform-scope-values). To ensure that `-sysroot` is only evaluated for your ARM builds you can do something like this:

```
arm-linux: {
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += --sysroot
}
```

You may need to change the scope, depending on the platform you're actually targetting.